# How to handle foreign character in get/post request in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a model class as:

```
case class CreateRole(   roleName: String, 
                         roleId: Int)
```

Now, I am passing post request json as:

{"roleName":"həˈlō", "roleId": 342}

After saving it in database, the get request should return həˈlō, but in our case it return h?'l?(here all the French characters are returned ?(question mark)).

Comment: You need to check the character encoding you're using both in Java and in the DB

Comment: When post request json interact Java/Scala controller, in between, French characters are replaced/changed with ?(question mark). Therefore, we don't have any option to write encoding code in Java/Scala, because French characters are already changed to h?'l?.

Comment: How are you serializing the data? Can you please create [mre]?

Comment: It is probably not a serialization issue: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/1IDO8RqQTICad1Fn25D7sA